# How to duplicate texture node without duplicating its settings?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, settings, duplicate

I want to have **2 nodes that use the same texture, but are interpreting it differently** (for example "no alpha" vs "premultiplied"). However, there doesn't seem to be any way to do that. All parameters stay the same between the texture nodes, no matter what I try (tried even **packing** the texture and adding a new - same - one from the folder; which, I don't see why it wouldn't work, since these are now 2 different textures - but it didn't).

I just want to use the same texture but with different settings.

[image: These settings change simultaneously between the nodes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make data single with the icon before the Fake User shield icon:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you need to make a duplicate of the image. You can do this by clicking on the number 2 next to the image name. If the image is for example "image.png", the duplicate image will be named "image.png.001". After that you can set the *Alpha* and *Color Space* for those images individually. Why I wrote "unfortunately" I'll explain below.

[image: duplicate image]

However you must be aware that these are now separate, unconnected images. If you for example paint on one of them, these changes will not be applied to the other image:

[image: independent images]

The problem is, things like *Color Space* or *Alpha* are set per image, they are not set per *Image Texture* node. This is why you have to make a duplicate image but it also means, the settings you choose in the *Image Texture* node will also be showing if you open the image in the *Image Editor* or *UV Editor* for example. And if you change them in the *Image/UV Editor*, these changes will be made in the *Shader Editor*, too.

As you can see, the settings in the *Image Editor* and the *Shader Editor* are the same for a specific image:

[image: comparison between settings]

If I would now change the *Alpha* setting in the *Image Editor*, the setting you see in the *Shader Editor* on the according *Image Texture* node will automatically change as well:

[image: changing the image settings]

I don't know if this is relevant for you since you just asked for how to be able to set different settings on two nodes, but I think this is important to keep in mind, just in case you change something on one image and are not aware that these changes are not transferred to the other image.

Comment: Technically, it's a duplicate of the image ***data-block***, so it's not actually creating twice the data (i.e. doubling the disk space used). Blender just happens to assign that data-block the same name as the image file name, extension and all. (A strategy to confuse newbies, I presume.) But as you have pointed out, duplicating results in a block ending in ".001", which is of course not a valid image file extension.

Comment: P.S. I am aware that you probably know this. My previous comment was mostly to help other readers who may come across your answer. I wasn't trying to split hairs. ;-)

Comment: I suppose I should also explain to readers that the ".001" image in your example that has a white scribble painted over it has not been saved (but is using system memory). When saved, if it is given the same file name, the original image will be overwritten. If the image is *not* saved before the .blend file is closed, that precious white scribble will be lost. May as well point out these Blender intricacies that users will eventually encounter.

Comment: @Mentalist Yes, I am aware of that but wanted to mainly show how it appears in the editor and called it "image" for simplicity, and because I didn't want to dive deep into the realm of data-blocks to explain to beginners. And honestly I had no big interest in expanding this topic since the simple "make the image texture node a single user" answer was already found sufficient and was accepted 